# Google Search Console Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, googlebot, google-search-console

Do I have a syntax error here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    async function showWidget(physicianId, locationId, format)
    {
        var response = await fetch('https://reviews.rater8.com/webwidget/api/ratingsummary/' + physicianId + '?format=' + format);
        var snippet = await response.text();
        document.getElementById(locationId).innerHTML = snippet;
    }
</script>
```

This function works, you can see the page live at:

https://reviews.rater8.com/webwidget/sample.html

However, Google doesn't see the content which I plug into the page dynamically, via the function. I used the Google Search Console to see why not, and discovered that Google is flagging the page with two errors:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
   https://reviews.rater8.com/webwidget/sample.html:12

(That is the keyword 'function' after the keyword 'async'.)

2. Uncaught ReferenceError: showWidget is not defined
   https://reviews.rater8.com/webwidget/sample.html:20

Naturally, if the function definition doesn't parse, then the function isn't going to be defined. I can eliminate the parsing error by removing the keyword async but then the function doesn't execute properly!

Comment: Actually, this question is specifically about programming. My question is specifically to inquire whether there is something wrong with the syntax of my javascript. The rest of the narrative is simply the context of where my javascript is being flagged as in error.

Comment: Alternatively, if I had known before what I know now, my question would have been - 'how can I re-implement this javascript without reliance on the await mechanism'? Is there any way I can change the title of my question at this point? If you feel that would more appropriately describe the nature of this question I will happily do that, if I am able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the job done without using the javascript await mechanism.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showWidget(physicianId, locationId, format)
    {
        fetch('https://reviews.rater8.com/webwidget/api/ratingsummary/' + physicianId + '?format=' + format)
            .then(function (response) {
                response.text()
                    .then(function (snippet) {
                        document.getElementById(locationId).innerHTML = snippet;
                    })
            })
    }
</script>
```

Google is able to see the content generated via this approach.